# How to fetch data from a website that requires permission using curl?

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I am familiar with the `curl` command in Linux. However, I want to know if there is a way to access a URL which when accessed asks for a user interaction/permission to proceed forward for example, asking for a license agreement whether user agrees or not.

Is there a way I can either skip this permission check or pass the "I agree" kind of argument in the `curl` command which takes me to the actual website data?

**Edit 1:** Some more information on how the user interaction/permission appears on the site:

When using a browser to visit the URL, the webpage asks the user to confirm if he agrees with the terms and license conditions and provides two options "I Agree" and "I Disagree". If the user clicks on "I Agree" he proceeds to the actual webpage.

I want to know if the same can be done via command line in a shell script using `curl` or equivalent?

**Edit 2:**

When using a browser (I used firefox) to visit the URL, the URL asks for the user permission only for the first time. Next time when I visit the URL it simply skips this and proceeds to the main site. I reckon the cookie for this session is saved by the browser and used next time onwards. Having this understanding, I tried to generate cookie files and use it through `curl` in the following way:

To generate cookie:

```
curl --cookie-jar cookies.txt http://url
```

To use the cookie:

```
curl --cookie cookies.txt http://url
```

But I could not succeed. I traced out the location of cookies saved by firefox and tried to use it in the same way but failed again. I think I am close but I am unable to take any step forward.

Comment: Can you please clarify how the user interaction/permission requirement appears on the site? It can be implemented many ways and I think 90% of them prevents you from using curl in a standalone way.

Comment: @GézaTörök Edited the question to add the details.

Comment: Still many ways can be imagined. Try to figure out what the page does when the user clicks on I Agree. If you are lucky, it simply leads you to another url, the one which you are in fact looking for, but i'm pretty sure it's not the case.
Most likely the server maintains a session in which it holds your choice upon the agreement. In this case you must somehow tell the server about your choice (a post request with specific variables set, clearly), then get the desired page. Note that you must preserve the cookie you received from the server and every request must contain it.

Comment: @GézaTörök The URL remains the same throughout. I think its most likely the case of server maintaining a session as mentioned by you.

Comment: Well, I think you must dig quite deep to achieve this. Not to mention, the site may change, making your efforts eventually useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the information given by [Géza Török](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4049863/g%C3%A9za-t%C3%B6r%C3%B6k) and [wick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2550808/wick) above and my own understanding I was able to achieve this. I used a Firefox browser to visit the URL and then located the cookies stored on the disk. After reading and understanding the content and format of the cookies I created my own cookie text file with appropriate response and passed it to the `curl` command in the following way to proceed to the main website:

```
curl --cookie cookies.txt http://url
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

As comments are rightly suggest there are many ways to implement this. To start with, I would install firebug (if using firefox) or press Ctrl+Shift+I in chrome to check what is going on after you hit the URL in question. If there are different objects associated with initial checks and the main function you will see it there, and decide whether curl will help.

Curl is just a tool to pull http objects. Probably the only case when it could replace browser's interaction is basic authentication, when you can supply keystring in request header. For the case you describe, http debugger would be the place to start.

Comment: I visited the URL using a browser (firefox) and observed that once I select the "I Agree" option, it doesn't prompt again to give the consent and goes directly to the main site. I think it saves this cookie and uses it every time for further sessions.